# How to give access rights to users with certain conditions?

Tags: security, odoo, odoo-10, access-rights

If there are four records created by four users. The Manager can be able to see all the records of all users. But a user should not be able view another user's record.

user – Can create/view/edit only his/her own record.

This is my need.

Thank  You in advance.

Comment: This is already available in Odoo. For example, check the record rules for Sales Order. Try creating sales order from different users and check.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create ir.rules. For example in your case it would be something like this:
For administrators:

```
<record id="manager_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">My first rule</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_your_model"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[(1,'=',1)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('your_manager_group'))]"/>
</record>
```

For other users:

```
<record id="others_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">My second rule</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_your_model"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
```

For more information about access rules you could visit [odoo_security](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/security.html), [access_rules](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/how-to-use-access-rights-and-record-rules-40960).

I hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem solved using domain like

Eg.
 `domain = [('user_id','=',user.id)]`

i hope it helps you